# Understanding the definition of $f(T)$ of functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Let $T$ be an element of a Banach Algebra, and $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum.
[image]

I don't understand the above definition, specially when I see the following equalities

$$f(T)S=\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1}S \ dz$$

and

$$Sf(T)=\oint f(z)S(z-T)^{-1} \ dz$$

If we were thinking of operators $B(X)$, then I would understand $f(T)S$ as $f(T)\circ S=\oint f(z)(z-T)^{-1}(S) \ dz$. However, I would not know how we would deduce the 2nd equality...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically, continuous linear maps can be moved in or out of integrals.

Comment: If you treat the integral as a Riemann-Stieltjes sum that converges in the norm of $B(X)$, you should be able to show what you want. Or use whatever definition you have for the integral.

Comment: can I ask from what book is this?

Comment: @Masacroso From Functional Analysis by Joseph Muscat

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks ;)

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks for your comment. By the way, what you suggest is valid for more general elements of Banach algebra other than $B(X)$?